# INSERT from servlet throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 

Tags: sql-server-2005, servlets, jdbc

I am using the code below to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database from a servlet. But it is throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

---

Code Snippet:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class InsertServlet extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException,IOException
{
    doGet(request,response);

}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException,IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    EmpDetailBean empdetailbean=new EmpDetailBean();
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt2=null;
    //ResultSet rs=null;
    String employeecode=request.getParameter("employeecode");
    pw.println(employeecode);
    empdetailbean.setEmployeecode(employeecode);
    try
    {   //String emp_code=(String)session.getAttribute("empcode");
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        //String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;" +  
               // "databaseName=test;user=sa;password= ;"; 

        //con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:leave1");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.217.7.3;databaseName=test;user=sa;password=123;");
        String query1="insert into leavetype(dbo.empcode) values(?)";

        pstmt2=con.prepareStatement(query1);
        pstmt2.setString(1,empdetailbean.getEmployeecode());

        int k=pstmt2.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(k);
        pstmt2.close();    

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   pw.println("exception"+ e);

    }


}

}
```

**the log file shows**

```
May 2, 2012 11:34:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
May 2, 2012 11:34:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Comment: You need to put the driver jar in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831565/java-servlet-connecting-to-sql-server-tutorial

Comment: i have sqljdbc_4.0\enu. I have executed xa_install and put sqljdbc_xa.dll into the bin folder of mysql2005.I have sqljdbc4.jar file into enu where do i put.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` as Driver then `sqljdbc.jar` is required to be
present in your classpath which is `WEB-INF\lib`.

If you want to user Jtds Driver Check this [link](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#driverImplementation) for Driver and databse URL

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the Jar file for the JDBC Connectivity is missing from the war file that you have deployed. could you please ensure that the lib files are getting packaged with war file properly

Comment: lib files are packaged the path is D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\lib.which jar file is it jtds-1.2.2.jar

Comment: @AbhiruchiSharma Are you guys using JDTS jar , then i think the driver class name remains "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"  , otherwise if u are using MS JDBC , then that jar file should be there